# Easiest way to send an Email from the command line, using windows 2003 R2

Tags: windows-server-2003, email, command-line-interface

I have a Windows 2003 R2 server and I want to send an email from the command line.  This server does not have the SMTP service configured.  Is there a one liner that will let me send an email?  My specific use case at the moment is to send an email when a performance alert is triggered, but it would be useful in general.

I'm hoping for something like

```
foomail -t peter@example.org -f blah@example.org -m "Alert!  the sky is falling"
```

**Update:**  I would much prefer a solution that does not involve installing 3rd party software.

Comment: Utilities like blat and sendemail don't require installation. They're both freestanding exe files.

Comment: I guess I have to accept that I need to at the very least copy an exe (either blat or powershell) to each machine.  If that's the case, then blat is very easy to use.  Thanks.  I still wonder why MS left this feature out, considering how many other less useful ones they put in to the standard distro.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'd try [blat](http://www.blat.net/).  You could write a vbscript but there is no built in executable to send mail

Comment: seconding blat. It can be a bit picky about passing parameters directly from the command line, but once you nail it, does exactly what the OP needs.

Comment: I've been using blat for years with great success.  However, If I was writing in powershell, I'd switch.

Comment: Does blat able to work as send mail path for PHP on Windows?

Answer (score 14):

Would you consider powershell rather than cmd.exe? If so, sending mail is built in:

```
$SmtpClient = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient
$SmtpServer = "your.mail.host.com"
$SmtpClient.host = $SmtpServer 

$From = "Me <User@example.com>"
$To = User2@example.com
$Title = "Subject"
$Body = "Body Text" 
$SmtpClient.Send($From,$To,$Title,$Body)
```

To make a one liner, save the following to a powershell script file (sendmail.ps1):

```
   param(  
        [string] $From = "from@example.com",
        [string] $To = "to@example.com",
        [string] $Title = "title",
        [string] $Body = "body"
    )
    $SmtpClient = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient
    $SmtpServer = "your.mail.host.com"
    $SmtpClient.host = $SmtpServer 
    $SmtpClient.Send($From,$To,$Title,$Body)
```

(make sure to change the smtpserver to be your real one)

Then you can call it using:

```
powershell.exe c:\path\to\sendmail.ps1 "from@example.com" "to@example.com" "title" "body"
```

Comment: powershell would also have to be installed, otherwise I would have prefered it over vbscript.

Comment: Nice answer.  Just one minor change, the arguments need to be single quotes.

Answer (score 6):

I've used [bmail](http://www.beyondlogic.org/solutions/cmdlinemail/cmdlinemail.htm) with great success in the past.

Usage (copied from website)

```
C:\>bmail /?

    Command Line SMTP Emailer V1.07
    Copyright(C) 2002-2004 Craig.Peacock@beyondlogic.org
    Usage: bmail [options]
            -s    SMTP Server Name
            -p    SMTP Port Number (optional, defaults to 25)
            -t    To: Address
            -f    From: Address
            -b    Text Body of Message (optional)
            -h    Generate Headers
            -a    Subject (optional)
            -m    Filename (optional) Use file as Body of Message
                -c    Prefix above file with CR/LF to separate body from header
                -d    Debug (Show all mail server communications)
```

Comment: I have to admit, I was hoping for a built in solution, though Jim's answer seems to imply that was a bit naive of me...

Answer (score 2):

Try free Mail Alert Simple Mailer:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/mail-alert/

It supports SSL/TLS mail servers like gmail and its' easy to configure.

Comment: It supports SSL too.

Answer (score 0):

One more command-line mailer program:

- [mailsend](https://github.com/muquit/mailsend)

It supports SSL too.

Answer (score 0):

```
sendEmail -f %from_addr% -t %to_addr% -u "Subject Line" -m "Message" -s %smtp_server%
```

The simplest Win utility I found and used in production environment. Standalone executable, without installation or mandated configuration.
Supports both non-TLS and TLS. And has a debugger, which is sometimes helpful.

Executable can found here:

http://caspian.dotconf.net/menu/Software/SendEmail/#download